# Refresh/Reload Form using timer in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have messed with this long enough and had to come for help. I am reading in some text file values on form_load. I want to refresh/reload the form every 5 minutes (Disregard my test time). The form loads and runs ok, but after a couple of minutes it seems to crash and I get an error at timer.start. The time until it crashes is very random. I don't understand enough yet about timers, so hopefully someone can tell me where I am going wrong here.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim timer = New Timer
    timer.Interval = 30 * 1000
    NewMethod(timer)
    timer.Start()

    '''Run other code
End Sub

Private Sub NewMethod(timer As Timer)
     AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf Timer1_Tick
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
   Form1_Load(Me, e:=Nothing)
End Sub
```

Comment: "I get an error at timer.start". What is the error?

Comment: The error was "error creating window handle"

Comment: You're looking at this from the wrong perspective. The `Form1_Load()` method is not special in terms of rebuilding or re-initializing the form's contents. It only does the things you tell it to. If you want to do thing like reload a text file, you need a method to do exactly those things. Then use this method for the timer's tick event.

Comment: After 2 minutes, you'll have a lot of `Timer.Tick` events that raise ~at the same time. Each time you `AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf Timer1_Tick`, you add another handler which, when called by the Timer, will call `Form1_Load`, adding a new event handler each. You need to move what's in `Run other code` in a method and call that method from `Form.Load` and `Timer.Tick`. Using one event handler.

Comment: Calling `Form1_Load(Me, e:=Nothing)` doesn't refresh the form. The method that `Handles MyBase.Load` is called for you to execute any code you want when the form loads.

Comment: Yes, this code will always crash with this error.  It creates an exponentially increasing number of timers.  Since it never stops a timer and never disposes any and every Tick creates more ticking timers.  Timer needs a window to generate the Tick event, you can't see it.  After the code created ten thousand of them, the OS pulls the plug and won't let it create more, "error creating window handle" is the diagnostic.  You'll have to re-think this, one timer is enough to refresh form content.

Comment: Lots of great observations from you guys, I appreciate it. Could someone give me an example of how this should be used correctly? If I am reading a text file in to a listbox and I need it updated every 5 minutes, what is the correct way to handle this? I have found way too many things regarding the use of timers, so I want to learn the most efficient use of it.